# How to use Notify.js with button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ive downloaded Notify.js'files and put them in root of webpage. im trying to test it but i didn't get anything when click on button

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script src="notify.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input name="notif" type="button" value="Shoow notif" onclick="$(".elem-demo").notify("Hello Box");">
</body>

</html>
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: How about loading jQuery?

Comment: Do you mean this? <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @undefined This is the Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25582016/3176270

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your answer and working:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="notify.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input name="notif" type="button" value="Shoow notif" onclick="$('.elem-demo').notify('Hello Box');"/>

<div class="elem-demo">a Box</div>
</body>

</html>
```

1-You forgot to include jquery to your file.

2-You should create an element that has a *elem-demo* class

3-Your javascript had a problem! You can't use double-quotation and it's child has double-quotation too.

here is your code example, and then my code:

```
onclick="$(".elem-demo").notify("Hello Box");"  //Your code

onclick="$('.elem-demo').notify('Hello Box');"  //My code
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, and I have an question. 
How to make this work? $(".pos-demo").notify(
  "I'm left of the box", 
  { position:"left" }
); ?

Comment: @EddHakobyan your code is true, $(".pos-demo").notify( "I'm left of the box", { position:"left" } );  but maybe its for **quotation** again